# Junit test Failed not finding AssertArrayEquals Method in Assert class

Tags: junit4

I am using Junit 4.1. When I tried to use AssertArrayEquals(...) it's not finding that method. I tried importing everything by `import static org.junit.Assert.*;`. I searched in the jar file but I didn't find this method, and need suggestions to resolve this.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ArraysCompareTest {

    @Test
    public void testArraySort() {
        int [] actual= {8,7,6,5};
        int [] expected= {5,6,7,8};
        Arrays.sort(actual);
        //it fails because it checks object references not content
        assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);

    }
}
```

The problem here is Assert class is not showing AssertArrayEquals in suggestion.

Comment: What is your pom file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the JUnit4 jar? Assert.AssertArrayEquals wasn't present in JUnit3 and before.